# How to antialias SVG text in Firefox

Tags: firefox, svg, antialiasing

Does anyone know the best way to anti-alias svg text that will work in Firefox?

I tried text-antialias:true but this has no effect, and also I tried using a stroke paint but this just thickens up the font and is not what I like.

Example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<svg height="100" width="500">
<text y="50" x="250" text-anchor="middle" style="font-size: 40px" >Hello</text>
</svg>
</body>
</html>
```

I have uploaded this to http://jsfiddle.net/KJhrY/

This example appears antialiased in IE9 on my PC (Windows)

Comment: This looks anti-aliased just fine on firefox 17/Vista

Comment: @Michael - yes it works fine on another PC with Firefox. Although I was using v18 on the machine where it didn't work. Maybe anti-aliasing is something I can't assume to be working for all my viewers, at least at the moment.

Comment: ouch - yeah I see it on FF18/OSX. I'd file a bug with mozilla.

Comment: i know I guess the only way to control exactly what the user sees is to use an image generated on the server, or maybe a canvas is the way to go.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Firefox 25 [will have support](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=857142#c83) for the mox-osx-font-smoothing attribute!

So for firefox 25 you can use:

```
.yourclass{
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
```

Firefox 25 <strike>will probably be released somewhere at the [end of Oktober](https://wiki.mozilla.org/RapidRelease/Calendar)</strike> was released on 2013-10-29.
Nightly builds can be found at http://nightly.mozilla.org/

Comment: Working at least on OSX 10.7.5 with Firefox 25 public release.

Answer (score 2):

Try "text-rendering" attribute.
text-rendering = "optimizeLegibility"

Comment: Firedox does not support this at the moment.

Comment: Tried it: Can't see, that this had any impact.